# Ionic - native dialogs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a form and I am displaying an error messages in it with `ng-show` like this:

```
<div class="errors">
          <p ng-show="errorMessage" ng-class="error">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
</div>
```

I am sending an error message form a controller like this:

```
$scope.login = function(form) {
    if (!form.$valid) {
      return;
    }

    var credentials = {
        phone: $scope.loginData.phone,
        password: $scope.loginData.password
    };

    $auth.login(credentials).then(function(response) {
        UserService.set(response.data.user);

        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
          disableBack: true
        });

        $state.go('main.front');
    }, function(error) {
        navigator.notification.alert("Feil brukernavn eller passord.");
    });
  }
```

I would like to instead of displaying an error on the page, to display with native device dialogs alert. But I get an error of:

> ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: Cannot read property 'alert' of
>   undefined

Updated code:

```
function(error) {
      console.log('error');
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      function onDeviceReady() {
      navigator.notification.alert(
        "Feil brukernavn eller passord.",   // the message
        function() {},                      // a callback
        "Title",                            // a title
        "OK"                                // the button text
        );
      }
    });
```

I have updated code like this, and when I test it with ionic serve in the browser, I don't get anymore any errors, but no alert shows up.
I have done `cordova platform ls` in terminal and I get:

```
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
```

**Updated code 2**

As suggested, it works on emulators, when I do for example ionic emulate ios, but still not working in a browser, when I do ionic serve:

```
$scope.login = function(form) {
    if (!form.$valid) {
      return;
    }

    var credentials = {
        phone: $scope.loginData.phone,
        password: $scope.loginData.password
    };

    $auth.login(credentials).then(function(response) {
        UserService.set(response.data.user);

        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
          disableBack: true
        });

        $state.go('main.front');
    }, function(error) {
    console.log('error');
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

      function onDeviceReady() {
        if (navigator.notification && navigator.notification.alert) {
          navigator.notification.alert(
            "Feil brukernavn eller passord.",   // the message
            function() {},                      // a callback
            "Title",                            // a title
            "OK"                                // the button text
          );
        } else {
          alert("Feil brukernavn eller passord.");
          // callbackFunction(); if you need one
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Don't do a deviceready eventlistener inside your callback function

Comment: Could you please show how the code should look then?

Comment: you can display alerts using $ionicPopup.alert( {...} ) -> [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup)

Comment: @matt93 yes and that works fine, but I need native dialogs

Comment: I have never tried to use cordova-plugin-dialogs on a browser, but as the documentation, it should work. Have you added browser as a platform? what do you see when you run `cordova plugin ls` from CLI?

Comment: @ThilakRao I get: cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
                              cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"

Comment: @marco can you post the output of `cordova platform ls`? 

To help you out, I cloned [this](https://github.com/loicknuchel/ionic-starter), but I ran into the same problem you did.

Comment: @ThilakRao well when I do cordova platform ls in terminal I get like I wrote previously:     cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification" cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"

Comment: @Marco Are you sure? `cordova platform ls` is supposed to list all platforms that are installed. `cordova plugin ls` should be listing all the plugins installed.

Comment: sorry, when I run platform ls I get: Installed platforms:
  ios 4.1.1
Available platforms: 
  amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
  android ~5.1.1
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0
  browser ~4.1.0
  firefoxos ~3.6.3
  osx ~4.0.1
  webos ~3.7.0

Comment: @Marco Did you included cordova.js file in your html and you should ensure to use plugin code inside platform ready function

Comment: I have included the cordova.js file, and alerts are working fine when I do emulate ios, they are only not working in the browser

Comment: @Marco I hope you were able to use the fallback that I provided. If not, let me know what went wrong. I'm really hoping to win this bounty :)

Comment: Why do you have the `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` function in your code? You should not need it when it's called when you know the device is actually ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use native alerts in an Ionic Framework application you need to first install the Cordova Dialogs plugin with:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

This plugin is not included in the Ionic Framework by default. After installing the plugin you can use the alert dialog with:

```
navigator.notification.alert(
  "Feil brukernavn eller passord.",   // the message
  function() {},                      // a callback
  "Title",                            // a title
  "OK"                                // the button text
);
```

Remember the following:

> Although the object is attached to the global scoped navigator, it is not available until after the deviceready event.

You can also see the theme of the dialogs for example in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

You can modify the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"` bit of this code if there's need.

Here is the documentation for [Cordova Dialogs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs).

**UPDATE based on comment:**

After installing the plugin you should compile the app again to include the plugin in your platform build. You probably can do this straight with `ionic state restore` but if not just add and remove the platform like this:

```
cordova platform remove android // OR ionic platform remove android
cordova platform add android    // OR ionic platform add android
```

The ionic state restore I was talking about:

```
ionic state restore
```

Then place the code in your contoller:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  navigator.notification.alert(
    "Feil brukernavn eller passord.",   // the message
    function() {},                      // a callback
    "Title",                            // a title
    "OK"                                // the button text
  );
}
```

After this just do `ionic run android` or what ever you want and it should show the alert dialog.

**EDIT 2 based on realisation:**

Ok so you probably are wondering why it does not work in a browser? As my example above only works on mobile devices. If you want it working also on a browser please use a method described below by @Thilak like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  if (navigator.notification && navigator.notification.alert) {
    navigator.notification.alert(
      "Feil brukernavn eller passord.",   // the message
      function() {},                      // a callback
      "Title",                            // a title
      "OK"                                // the button text
    );
  } else {
    alert("Feil brukernavn eller passord.");
    // callbackFunction(); if you need one
  }
}
```

Comment: I did install plugin, I just don't know where exactly should I put this piece of code, into run function or $ionicPlatform.ready:   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(navigator.notification);
}

Comment: If you are calling this alert on the login function you can place it directly there. No need for the document ready stuff.

Comment: I have updated code in the question, but no alert renders.

Comment: Did you install the plugin correctly? I had a wrong command in my answer before. You should install the plugin with command `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs`

Comment: yes, I did install it correctly since it shows up on my list when I do cordova platform ls

Comment: I updated my answer...please try it the way I described. Your function had some format issues also.

Comment: **Don't** add eventlisteners in your `error` function

Comment: You're right...this was just a `copy -> fix format issues -> paste` from the question. Edited to correct this issue.

Comment: I did ionic state restore and I have the same code as you do, but still not alert pops up

Comment: Am I correct to assume you are testing with a browser? If so I added a second edit with a idea from below answer by @Thilak

Comment: I am testing with ionic serve in the browser and I have tried your suggestions but it is still not working

Comment: If you can't show a normal alert in your browser then I can't imagine what could be wrong and I'm not going to be able to help you...what browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you were lead astray because of incorrect documentation of `cordova-plugin-dialogs`. [Readme](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/README.md) lists browser as a supported platform, but the plugin does not fallback to window.alert, if you call navigator.notification.alert (as one would expect).

To test this, I cloned an [ionic seed project](https://github.com/loicknuchel/ionic-starter), tried to add `browser` as a platform, but navigator.notification is still undefined.

Here's a simple workaround:

```
  function showAlert(message, callback, title, buttonName) {
      title = title || "Default";
      buttonName = buttonName || 'OK';
      if (navigator.notification && navigator.notification.alert) {

          navigator.notification.alert(
              message, // message
              callback, // callback
              title, // title
              buttonName // buttonName
          );

      } else {
          alert(message);
          callback();
      }
  }
```

It simply detects whether `navigator.notification` and `navigator.notification.alert` are available, and provides appropriate fallback for the browser.

Comment: Can you put breakpoint, and step through the code? I hope you were able to short this out.